# How/ does AMP impact accessibility?

Tags: accessibility, amp-html

There's been a few questions floating around questioning whether AMP pages hinder accessibility, can someone point me in the right direction as to where I can find this out?

From what I understand about AMP, it doesn't however I have no concrete evidence of this. A client is very keen when it comes to web accessibility, so I do not want to recommend using AMP if it has a chance of negatively impacting accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

My personal take: You can see if the issues (most are fixed):

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues?q=label%3A%22Related+to%3A+Accessibility%22

concerns you or your client. Since AMP is still HTML, all accessibility techniques for HTML are applicable. Accessibility of complex AMP components may need the AMP Project team to resolve. My experience with AMP is that it is better in accessibility since it is designed for more accessibility-challenged mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used amp but from a quick look at ampbyexample.com, it looks like you can control a lot of the html that's generated, which is a good thing.  If amp does not use semantic html elements (such as <table>, <ul>, <h2>, etc), then hopefully you can customize the generated code to add ARIA attributes to make up for the shortcomings (such as [`role="table"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#table), [`role="list"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#list), [`role="heading"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#heading) and [`aria-level="2`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-level), respectively).

Their [date picker](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-date-picker/) looked pretty decent.  It worked well with a keyboard and a screen reader mostly handled it.